# firefox extension show MFC dialog as embedded user interface (convert into plugin)?

Tags: firefox-addon, npapi, browser-plugin

I have firefox extension that i want to change into plugin. what I want to achieve is that I have a MFC dialog box that I want to show as embedded in browser in response to some event. Can I do that. What will I have to do to change extension into plugin.

Comment: I'd look at using FireBreath to make it a plugin, but FireBreath and MFC don't play nice because FireBreath is built on ATL...

Comment: Some reference here: http://forum.firebreath.org/topic/310/